# Python algorithm to summ N numbers

Tags: python

I'm just started in python, trying to solve this:

You need to place `"+"` between numbers 123...N, to have `M` as a result

Example:

1. In: 5 15

   Out: 1+2+3+4+5=15
2. In: 4 46

   Out: 12+34=46

I was searching all over Internet, but found none.

Comment: You need a depth first search over the possibilities, possibly using dynamic programming to avoid repeated work. This isn't a beginner task.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

**This code works only for** one `+` sign.

**[1]Code:-**

```
n=input("Input number: ")
target=input("Input the target value: ")
total=0
lis=[str(i) for i in range(1,int(n)+1)]
flag=True
#print(lis)
for i in range(len(lis)):
    #print(lis[:i],lis[i:])
    left_side="".join(lis[:i])
    #print(left_side)
    right_side="".join(lis[i:])
    #print(right_side)
    temp=left_side+"+"+right_side
    total=eval(temp)
    #print(total)
    if total==int(target):
        print(left_side+"+"+right_side+" gives output: "+target)
        flag=False
        break
if flag:  #No target value found
    print("There is no value which sum up to target")
```

**Output:-**
#Testcase1: **When Target is achievable.**

```
Input number: 4
Input the target value: 46
12+34 gives output: 46
```

#Testcase2: **When Target is not achievable**

```
Input number: 8
Input the target value: 345
There is no value which sum up to target
```

A correct solution, which works on both examples given in the question and on other problems which require more than one + sign, can be found in Paul Hankin's answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74741043/1400793

Comment: Thank you
I've added check for simple summ of all numbers and its done i guess =-)

Comment: This code doesn't work on example 1: `In: 5 15`, which should give `1+2+3+4+5`. This answer assumes there's exactly one `+` inserted in the string, but example 1 in the question shows that there can be up to n-1 plusses. For example `In: 6 174` should give `123+45+6`.

Comment: Oh man!! thanks now i realise my error..   don't know why the question asker said my answer is correct..! can you help to make the code correct..

Comment: Yes, I added a comment to the question on how to solve it.

Comment: You copied my answer into yours, which although you gave credit seems unfair to me. I edited it to provide a link to my answer instead.

Comment: sorry for the unfair.. if you wanted i can delete my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can solve the problem by doing a depth-first search. This code tries all possible numbers formed from the last digits (n-i+1, n-i+2, ..., n), and then recurses to find all solutions for the reduced target. It outputs all solution (since there can be more than one).

```
def s(n, target):
    for i in range(1, n+1):
        d = int(''.join(str(n-i+j+1) for j in range(i)))
        if i == n and target == d:
            yield f'{d}'
        else:
            for r in s(n - i, target-d):
                yield f'{r}+{d}'


cases = [(4, 46), (5, 15), (6, 174), (4, 1234), (3, 15), (3, 24), (9, 90), (9, 91)]
for c in cases:
    print(f'{c}:', ', '.join(s(*c)))
```

Output:

```
(4, 46): 12+34
(5, 15): 1+2+3+4+5
(6, 174): 123+45+6
(4, 1234): 1234
(3, 15): 12+3
(3, 24): 1+23
(9, 90): 12+3+45+6+7+8+9, 1+2+3+4+56+7+8+9
(9, 91):
```